# PHP : rmdir deletes last file by alphabetical order

Tags: php, rmdir, alphabetical-sort

I am stuck would apreciate some assistance!
Whenever I wish to delete a file it deletes the last file in alphabetical order this is frustrating since PHP never fails me like this, am I missing something..?

Here is the code:

```
function delete_files($dir) {
if (is_file($dir)) {
return @unlink($dir);
}elseif (is_dir($dir)) {
$scan = glob(rtrim($dir,'/').'/*');
foreach($scan as $index=>$path) {
recursiveDelete($path);
}return @rmdir($dir);
}
}
```

Function called by: delete_files('folder/gallery/targetfolder');

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Where is the function `recursiveDelete()` coming from ? Seeing how it works, maybe you just meant to call `delete_files($path)` instead of `recursiveDelete($path)`.

Comment: This was not the issue, but did resolve a future issue, just tested to delete the last folder with images and it did not work, however with your suggestion works like a charm!